# spring JPA - delete by marking the entry

Tags: spring, jpa

I would like to know if Spring or JPA has something implemented to take care of this problem.

In Entity Framework there is something similar with this.

When I want to delete an object, I don't want to remove it from the database. Instead I want to mark it as deleted by using a datetime field.

Comment: You mean datetime will set on "delete" else it is null ? .... afaik there isnt a similar method in jpa, but you can add a datefield to database an use it for search "not deleted" (null field) entitys.

Comment: Is it just for one entity or all entities in your model?  You can create your own implementation of a Spring Data JPA repository that overrides the default `delete` method.

Comment: I am modeling my application by DDD so if I delete an entry from a superior class, it should not show the underlying relations. So it is enough only for one entity, but I will take in consideration overriding the "delete" method.